# Call another page in forms

Tags: plugins, forms, template-redirect

I am doing some practice for WordPress plugin. In plugin I am working on a form and what I need is to call another page on submission. I have tried that but nothing seems to work.

```
<form method = "Post" action = "some_file.php">

</form>
```

Comment: Where is this form located? On WordPress admin or on the front end?

Comment: Form is inside a plugin in a file. It is accessed from admin panel and open a new page.

Comment: More helpful tutorial: [How to submit the form in WordPress](https://devnote.in/how-to-submit-the-form-in-wordpress/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress has a generic handler to deal with all forms - admin-post.php.

If you include a hidden field in your form called action, you can then hook in to a function of your choice with all the goodness of wordpress included.

```
echo "<form action='".get_admin_url()."admin-post.php' method='post'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='action' value='submit-form' />";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='hide' value='$ques' />";
{ Enter the rest of your first block of code from above here }
```

And then in your functions.php file (or any other php file that you have included via functions.php), you can use this method.

```
add_action('admin_post_submit-form', '_handle_form_action'); // If the user is logged in
add_action('admin_post_nopriv_submit-form', '_handle_form_action'); // If the user in not logged in
function _handle_form_action(){

    { Enter your second block of code from above here }

}
```